# Creating multiple JFrames with offset overlap

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to create a program that launches any number of sub windows. How can I make it that each subsequent window opened is opened shifted to the bottom right so all the windows can be seen at the same time?

I have been able to make this offset with a static variable but windows will eventually be put off screen. How can I prevent that?

To fully understand my question try launching multiple calculator windows and watch the behavior. Is there a way to emulate that in Java?

Here's what I'm doing currently

```
private static int locationOfset = 0;

public ATMWindow(ATM atm) {
    ...
    setBounds(500 + (50 * locationOfset), 300 + (50 * locationOfset), 450, 300);
    locationOfset++;
    ...
}
```

Before you suggest CardLayout or something similar, I truly do want multiple JFrames if you can believe it.

Comment: Calling `myJFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);` can place your GUI where the OS wants it, and often that's a good thing.

Comment: Use JInternalFrame - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: @Fishstick: good deal, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

First read and understand [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

The easiest way would be to use a `public static` field to maintain the current (or future) position, so that when ever you created a new frame you could use something like...

```
setLocation((currentX += LOCATION_OFFSET), (currentY += LOCATION_OFFSET));
```

Where `currentX` and `currentY` are `public static int` values that hold the current offset position and `LOCATION_OFFSET` is a `public static final int` value that maintains the amount of the offset.

`currentX` and `currentY` could be child values of the parent class or a utility class as you see fit

The most significant issue with this is that it's now possible to run a window off the users screen...